# read token after token from a file in haskell

Tags: haskell, visualhaskell

I want to read from a file in Visual Haskell Studio, token after token, by loading each time the next token in a variable.
For example: getNextToken.
Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Alex](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/), which is a lexer (which split a string into a list of tokens). Then you can do whatever you want with the token list. If you really want to "load" them and put them in a variable, in a procedural way , I'm not sure Haskell is the right language to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the right answer is somewhat complicated:

Use a parser combinator library like [Parsec](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Parsec) that will let you fully define the meaning of the word 'token', which varies from context to context.